Can I translate this property into the language of category theory?
Given a group $G$, there exists a nontrivial homomorphism to some nontrivial subgroup $H$.
This criterion is satisfied for nonsimple-abelian groups.
I don't have any clue how to translate this property or even demonstrate it in the category of abelian groups. Some guidance or references would be very helpful.

Upvoting just to counteract the downvotes, which I don't really understand. The question is stated clearly enough and contains all necessary context.

What exactly does nontrivial mean for you?

@hardmath
simple groups dose not satisfy the criterion

MathJax does not recognize \( and \) for in-line formulas. You must use $

By "nontrivial subgroup" do you mean $H$ with $1\neq H\neq G$, or just $1\neq H$? If you consider the improper subgroup to be nontrivial, then then $H=G$ and $\mathrm{id}_G$ works.

@ArturoMagidin H≠G or H≠1 the identity subgroup


This criterion is satisfied for abelian groups.

This is false. For example $\mathbb{Q}$ does not admit such a homomorphism because the image of any nontrivial homomorphism out of $\mathbb{Q}$ must be divisible, and the only nonzero divisible subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ is itself.
However it is true for finitely generated abelian groups (assuming that "nontrivial" means "nonzero" only) other than the simple ones; maybe you only tested on those examples.
Translating the condition into category theory isn't a problem, though. You just need to replace subgroups with monomorphisms.

Note that replacing "nontrivial subgroup" simply with "monomorphism" will fail to exclude the improper subgroup.

@Arturo: we also need to translate "nontrivial homomorphism"; this means a morphism which is not a zero morphism in the category of groups, or equivalently which does not factor through the terminal object (the trivial group).  This excludes the trivial subgroup. To exclude the whole group we just say "monomorphism which is not an isomorphism."

You need a bit more, because of non-Hopfian  groups that are co-Hopfian.

@Arturo: what do you mean? A nontrivial embedding of a group into itself is a monomorphism which is not an isomorphism. As far as I know this ought to qualify as a "nontrivial homomorphism to some nontrivial subgroup."

Sorry... I'm thinking of nontrivial map with an improper image... and writing too fast.

To expand on what Qiaochu Yuan said a bit, you can define a subgroup of $G$ as a subobject of $G$, i.e. some other group $H$ equipped with a monomorphism $H\hookrightarrow G$. Then you're looking for such an $H$ along with a "nontrivial" morphism $G\to H$.
However, I'm not sure how to characterise a nontrivial homomorphism in the category of groups. For the nontriviality condition, QC gave a straightforward condition in the comments: A morphism $f:G\to H$ is trivial iff it factors through 1, and nontrivial otherwise.
So given $G$ you're looking for $H$ such that there is a monomorphism $H\hookrightarrow G$ and a morphism $f:G\to H$ such that there does not exist $k:1\to H$ with $f = G\to 1 \xrightarrow{k} H$.

Write $1$ for the terminal object in the category of groups (the trivial group, defined categorically). A morphism $f : G \to H$ is trivial iff it factors through $1$, and nontrivial otherwise. In $\text{Set}$, for example, this condition defines the constant functions.

As the subgroup $H$ of $G$ is supposed to be non-trivial, you should also add the condition that the monomorphism $H \to G$ is not an isomorphism.
